# How was the Enterprise C model chosen on the D observation lounge?

Tags: star-trek

On the observation lounge of Enterprise D there are all the different model ships to have the name Enterprise. How was the side view of C designed? and by who? Did this force the creators of the Model used in "Yesterdays Enterprise" to have to try and make it like the gold one in observation?

[image]

Additional models as shown in Nemesis.

[image]

Comment: Just a note: you can include the Enterprise-B in this question, too. The first time we saw it was _Generations_.

Comment: Additionally the [Enterprise-A](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-A)), which was _not_ the same ship as the [Enterprise](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701)).

Answer (score 11):

The Enterprise-B is an [Excelsior class](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Excelsior_class):

[image: The iconic Excelsior class with its domed but also angular beveled saucer section reminiscent of the Constitution class and its unique hemispheric engineering hull.]

The Enterprise-D is a [Galaxy class](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Galaxy_class):

[image: The Galaxy class's much more streamlined/fluid lines, including oval cross-sectional engineering hull]

The Enterprise-C is an [Ambassador class](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ambassador_class) that is supposed to represent a transitional design bridging the Excelsior class and the Galaxy class. Here is the original concept with a very different drive section/secondary hull that looks like a cross between the Galaxy and the Excelsior's drive sections:
[image: The original concept painting by Andrew Probert showing a drive section with a more almond-shaped cross section like the Galaxy class, as well as Galaxy-class-style saucer section]

The Memory Alpha article about the [Ambassador class model](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ambassador_class_model) explains that the final studio model was created by Greg Jein based on a design Rick Sternbach developed from the original concept painting and design sketches by Andrew Probert. The original concept had more organic lines and smooth curves, looking much more like a blend of the Excelsior and Galaxy classes. But it was simplified because of time constraints imposed by "Yesterday's Enterprise":

[image: The final Ambassador class model has an angular-beveled saucer section like the Excelsior class and a semi-cylindrical drive section like the Constitution class.]

Source:

> The studio model was designed by Rick Sternbach, based on sketches as
>   well as on a design concept painting produced by Andrew Probert for
>   the first season of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*. The design was
>   intended to suggest an intermediate step between the Excelsior-class
>   and the Galaxy-class starships. A relief sculpture of Probert's design
>   was placed in the observation lounge aboard the USS Enterprise-D.
>   Unfortunately, the model was needed for "Yesterday's Enterprise" much
>   sooner than the time it would take to fabricate the smoother lines of
>   Probert's concept, requiring Sternbach's alterations which ended up on
>   Greg Jein's final model. As Sternbach later renumbered, elaborating in
>   detail on his thought processes,
>
> "The deadline for sketching and blueprinting the Ent-C was pretty
>   normal in that I had a few days preproduction to sketch up the ship as
>   first suggested in Andy Probert's color painting, get it approved as
>   an intermediate shape between the Excelsior and the Galaxy classes,
>   and then work up the blueprints. Greg Jein was given the miniature
>   job, as we know. I suppose it took about three or four days to draft
>   up the hull shape. The port elevation sketch was the first and,
>   ultimately, the only sketch view of the Ambassador class Enterprise-C
>   done for the TNG episode "Yesterday's Enterprise." Time constraints
>   dictated that the blueprints and filming miniature be started as soon
>   as possible, and the general look of the ship was quickly approved.
>
> "**The genesis of the design came from a small color painting done by
>   Andy Probert back in the early preproduction for Season 1, plus a
>   mental blending of the Excelsior/Enterprise-B and Galaxy class
>   Enterprise-D. While Andy's color sketch showed an elliptical cross
>   section for the engineering hull and an intended elliptical saucer
>   (not clearly visible but confirmed by Andy), the Enterprise-C would
>   require some simplifications if it were to be constructed in time for
>   filming. I began drawing up the blueprints with a circular saucer and
>   a circular cross section for the engineering hull, knowing that they
>   would make model maker Greg Jein's job markedly easier.** Swinging
>   compass arcs for the major saucer thickness changes and secondary hull
>   bulkheads took much less time in the drafting stage than calculating
>   ellipses, which is not impossible with pencil and tracing vellum
>   (using something called the trammel method), just tedious. With the
>   basic line work completed for a combined top/bottom view and a
>   fore/aft view, all of the expected details on a Starfleet ship were
>   added. Shield grid lines, phaser strips, lifeboat hatches, reaction
>   control thrusters, running lights, engineering access hatches, and
>   windows populated the surface.

Sternbach's design sketches:
[image: Sternbach's design sketches of the Enterprise-C / Ambassador class, showing the original Probert design and then the creation of the final design used for the studio model.]

Answer (score 1):

The decision, that the B will be an Excelsior class ship, was because of the Movies. They have established the Excelsior class as the successor of the Constitution class and although they preferred to make the A a Constitution class (because the model was much more detailed than the Excelsior one and because they thought, the fans would not want to have Kirk in a Excelsior class ship), they decided, that the B will be an Excelsior class. In universe it is justified, that the Excelsior was 2285 only a test bed for the Transwarp drive and they only decided afterwards to make it a standard design for star ships. So even if they put the B directly into production mode, it would not have been finished for several years (8, to be clear). So they just repainted the struggled Yorktown, whose crew were able to rescue themselves via the solar panel construction to a star base, to the new Enterprise A. The Excelsior was designated for Sulu, but he ran the mission in Movie 5 with the Enterprise, because they didn't had a new good pilot for the A yet and the Excelsior was in rebuilt to a normal warp ship.

But as the Yorktown was of course quite as old as the old Enterprise, which was put in service 2245, the A was only a solution for some time. Better said until the main crew would come to retire age (funnily Spock retired from Starfleet in the age of 60. T'Pol was 65 when she boarded the NX 01 the first time. He could, if he would have wanted, always gone to another ship, but he preferred to go in retirement with his friends (of whom all but McCoy and Scott will be presumably dead in 2369, I guess, when Vulcans wouldn't be so logical, they would went insane by having all their friends pass away before them :D)